# Свойство IsReadOnly в ICollection<T>

Tags: c#, коллекции

Пытаюсь разобраться в написании собственных коллекций (да и вообще по глубже разобраться в коллекциях).

Я сейчас в учебных целях пишу реализацию коллекции, которая наследует интерфейс `ICollection<T>`.

Такой вопрос, как должен себя вести метод add если в коллекции по умолчанию задано `IsReadOnly = true`?

Есть такие варианты как:

1. выбрасывать исключение если он был вызван (но это ужасно глупо);
2. не иметь ни какой реализации (получается метод пустышка только для интерфейса, я не уверен, что это нормально);
3. скрывать его под явной реализацией интерфейса и делать реализацию пустой (то же самое, что и в предыдущем варианте только может чуть лучше).

Comment: Мой ответ - 1. И это ни разу не глупо. Если есть несоотвествующее поведение - разработчик должен знать об этом.

Comment: Если массив привести к этому интерфейсу и вызвать метод `Add`, выбрасывается исключение `NotSupportedException: Коллекция имела фиксированный размер`.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Именно так, бросать исключение. Ничего глупого в этом нет: если операцию невозможно выполнить, нужно как можно громче заявить об этом, а не притворяться, что всё идёт как надо. В противном случае программист добавит элементы в коллекцию, не заметит ошибку, и будет считать, что ничего странного не происходит. Отловить логическую ошибку («я добавил элементы в коллекцию, но они там не появились») на порядок сложнее, чем поймать креш в виде необработанного исключения.

Наличие свойства `IsReadOnly` — ошибка в проектировании, сделанная ещё во времена .NET 1.0. Правильнее было бы иметь отдельный интерфейс `IReadOnlyList<T>` (который появился в .NET 4.5).

Comment: Я понял вас, похоже здесь действительно нет других вариантов. Спасибо за ответ)

Comment: @Snuppi: Пожалуйста!